# Line art for organic models

Tags: toon-shading

I've tried several methods to get line art highlighting, none with great results:

1. blender freestyle
2. blender line art

Both of the above are fairly fast and easy, but don't do well on my oddly shaped
models

3. Photoshop on Blender-rendered image

This one is time consuming and requires intermediate PS skills

4. Combination of Rhino 3d line creation, creating nurbs surfaces that are then
   rendered, then a doctored version of the render is brought into PS and aligned with a
   render image from blender

Number 4 gives the best results, but is time consuming, requires yet another
program (Rhino), and, of course, more skills

Adobe Illustrator can be substituted for the approaches above that specify
Photoshop.

Has anybody else solved the line art problem on organic models with some other approach?

I assume that the spectacular(and easy-to-get) results we see in examples are down to the
fact
that they are using hard surface modeling whereas I'm using organic.

Comment: Hello, could you add a screenshot showing an example of what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: Take a look at the Lightning boy shader addon, wich is quite powerful and flexible.

Comment: Thank you, Josh. I like to try before I buy.